# For a locally compact Polish space $X$, is the space of finite atomic measures locally compact?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I want to know whether the space of finite atomic measures one a locally compact Polish space is locally compact as well. I know this is true for the space of probability measures, but I don't know the answer for this more general case.